# P5 array intersection

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I'm trying to extract the values from one array from the index of another. I'm loading two text files using loadStrings, which is working fine. I'm loading that data into two separate arrays. The two text files are different lengths, the first contains three values - a line number and then an x and y coordinate. The second text file contains the line numbers of the data that I want to extract from the first text file. With only two months of coding behind, me this is an extremely daunting task that has left me completely stymied! My (very basic) code thus far is as follows:

```js
let data1;
let data2;
let parsedData1;
let parsedData2;
let combinedData;

function preload() {
  data1 = loadStrings('assets/data1.txt'); // load the data1 file
  data2 = loadStrings('assets/data2.txt'); // load the data2 file
  // console.log(data1);
  // console.log(data2);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);   
}

function draw() {
  noLoop();
  background(0);
  
  readData1()
  readData2()
}

function readData1() {
  parsedData1 = new Array(data1.length); // create an array for the parsed data

  for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    let parsedData1 = splitTokens(data1[i]);
    // console.log(data1); 
  }
}

function readData2() {
  let combinedData = concat(parsedData1, data2);
  // console.log(combinedData);
}
```

The text files that I'm loading contain the following:

text1:

```
1 200 50
2 100 25
3 200 63
4 123 456
5 124 200
6 700 500
7 600 500
8 200 121
9 300 100
```

text2:

```
3
5
8
```

The result that I'm seeking is:

```
3 150 100
5 124 200
8 200 121
```

Apparently the desired result can be achieved using loops, but I've yet to work out how!

Comment: How is the data actually formatted?  It looks like the values are just separated by spaces - is that the actual format?

Comment: hi! yes, just white space as a delimiter.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your example contains an error. The line 3 of text1 is not the same as your wanted result. Is this correct?

Comment: hi, sorry yes you are correct. i had doubled up on 3 and deleted the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned loops, here's how to do it with loops:

If you know that the "index numbers" in `data1.txt` don't skip any number:

```
for(let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
  let index = data2[i];
  console.log(data1[index]);
}
```

Otherwise, you can use nested loops like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
  let index = data2[i];
  for(let j = 0; j < data1.length; j++)
  {
    let line = data1[j];
    let lineArr = line.split(" ");
    if(lineArr[0] == index) {
      console.log(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks dietrich, that's exactly what i was looking for! i played around with the split method yesterday without much luck, now I realise where I have gone wrong. you've helped me a great deal and I appreciate it immensely!

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare the two strings, they need to be in arrays (or something similar).

Have a look at:

```js
  let text1 = document.getElementById("originaltext").innerHTML.trimRight();
  let compare1 = document.getElementById("comparevalues").innerHTML.trimRight();
  let a1 = text1.split("\n");
  console.log(a1);
  let c1 = compare1.split("\n");
  console.log(c1);
  const r1 = a1.filter(a => c1.includes(a.split(" ")[0]));
  console.log(r1);
```

```html
<pre id="originaltext">
1 200 50
2 100 25
3 200 63
4 123 456
5 124 200
6 700 500
7 600 500
8 200 121
9 300 100
</pre>
<pre id="comparevalues">
3
5
8
</pre>
```

This reads the strings from PRE tags in the example (but would be from your original text strings) and converts them into arrays.  Using "includes" filters the first list if the first number appears in the second list and returns a new array of the results

Comment: If you need the results to be in a string format, with each result on separate lines, add: console.log(r1.toString().replace(/[,]/g, "\n"));

Comment: Also note that, if you change this to match your requirements, it is necessary to include the .trimRight() function to remove whitespace from the text - this gets rid of any spare linefeeds at the end, which could cause problems for the rest of the code